# What can go wrong if I don't test my flutter app on Android physical device?

Tags: android, flutter, release, simulator

I have a flutter app that I have tested on multiple Android and iOS simulators and also a few iOS physical devices and it works well on all. However, I do not have an Android physical device to test my app with.

Do I have any cheap options to get an Android physical device here in the US? Also, if I can't test it on a physical device, what things could go wrong? As for native device features, I use location services, camera and gallery in my app.

Thanks!

Comment: Using avd wouldn't be the same as testing the app on a physical device. You really won't see how fast or slow your app runs in the device and wouldn't be able to see many other things such as camera (taking photos with it and not using stock photos). You also would have a harder time checking if your app looks good at different screen sizes and resolutions. If I were you, I would buy an old second hand android phone. It would be good to test your app in an old phone to check if it is performant even on low end devices.

Comment: I see. Do you think/know if the BLU smartphones are good enough for testing?

Comment: any would do, preferably those low end devices that run android 4.0 - 5.1

Comment: You can create a alpha/beta release and ask friends/family/co-workers who do have android to give it a try

Comment: From personal experience - it will be good if you're not using some 3rd party plugin's that do use native platform channels. Some plugins were giving no errors using AVD but had errors while using some real devices (ex.: SMS Autofill plugin was good for samsung phones, but had errors while trying to run it using Xiaomi phones).